# How to log Properties data as JSON instead of XML in serilog SQL sink

Tags: json, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I use Serilog for logging in Asp.net core web api. I configured it to use SQL sink and it does the logging in the log table with the Properties column data as XML.

How can I configure Serilog to log the Properties column data as JSON instead of XML?

Below is my appsettings.json file content. I installed Serilog.Formatting.Compact package and added the formatter setting in the appsettings.json. But still the Properties column data is in  XML.

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact",
          "tableName": "Log"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

How you do it is super confusing and not inline with some of the other libraries.

First here is an Args property of a config for MSSQLServerSink

```
"Args": {
    "tableName": "TestMvcClient",
    "schemaName": "dbo",
    "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
    "columnOptionsSection": {
        "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ], /* Use JSON Column LogEvent */
        "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ], /* Remove XML Column Properties */
    }
}
```

You can find it and 20+ other settings at the Serilog source.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#custom-property-columns

Comment: This answer works -- just add the LogEvent column and remove the Properties column.

Comment: Yeah not sure why I got downvoted. I hope it helps @Jovie

Answer (score -2):

That's a limitation of SQL Server, itself, not Serilog. SQL Server doesn't support JSON, but it does have an XML column type, which is why that's used by Serilog there.

Comment: Hi 

Not sure i agree with your comment about it not supporting JSON. Its does support JSON but in  NVARCHAR(MAX) field. 



https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: MS SQL server DOES supports JSON. Please review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15